# Help with Procedural Building Interior Stairs (Geo Nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I'm trying to build a geo node setup that allows users to make a building interior.

I'm running into an issue adding in stairs. I want to add a delete geometry node to remove the ground floor faces where the stairs poke out so that they arent intersecting.

[image]

I was able to use this setup here with a raycast node to create this "cut away" around the proximity of the instanced stairs but I'm having trouble controling the shape of the cut away so that its only in this shape (shown here):
[image]

If anyone knows a fix I would greatly appreciate it!